# БПФ и построение частотных графиков по введённым данным

Tags: c#

Добрый день интересуют ответы на такие вопросы
Поисковик по вопросам выдал подобные вопросы,но там информация немного иного типа.

1)В Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 предусмотрена такая возможность чтобы по формуле потом на форму вывести частотный синусоидный график и спектральный график?

Я слышал нужны какие-то платные библиотеки или я могу посредством PictureBox или TChart построить подобие частотного-синусоидного графика или спектрального?
Документацию и свойства Chart только на английском нашёл,не знаете где на русском языке есть?
Хочу подробно ознакомится с возможностями этого компонента.

В Делфи7 такое просто было возможно,а как обстоит дело с Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 C#?

2)fft,algolib обязательно скачивать?
Это в случае если я попытаюсь по формулам реализовывать Быстрое преобразование Фурье и Обратное преобразование Фурье с выводом результатов на частотные графики и спектральные.

Я пишу дипломный проект и 1-ый шаг состоит в том что я ввожу период и амплитуду,в процессе я на нахожу частоту и перехожу к формуле БПФ,а оттуда уже вывожу в графическом виде.

Если будут ещё теоретические вопросы то буду обновлять.
КОД МНЕ НЕ НУЖЕН.
формат вопрос-ответ,если вас не затруднит.

Comment: Вообще это два разных вопроса.
Visual Studio - среда разработки. Может в ней и нет нужных вам "компонентов" для рисования, может и есть. В любом случае нужный код можно написать самому. И Студия для этого более чем достаточна.

Comment: а как вы делали это в Delphi7?

Comment: Если проблема решена, то вам стоит отметить правильный ответ галочкой слева а не менять заголовок вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас в кучу смешались разу несколько вопросов. Давайте их разделим.

1. Какая-то часть программы должна уметь рисовать графики. Для C# есть интересный компонент ZedGraph, по-русски про него можно почитать [здесь](http://jenyay.net/Programming/ZedGraph).
2. Кто-то должен уметь рассчитывать спектр сигнала. В языке C# для этого нет встроенных средств. Поэтому Вы можете ли сами писать БПФ или использовать готовые библиотеки.